# Display PHP Errors in IIS

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to get PHP errors to display on the screen using IIS vrs 8.5 and PHP vrs 5.2.17, but I continue to get the IIS 500 error http page, or a blank screen. I have already found numerous SO posts that have supposed fixes, but nothing on them has fixed my problem yet. Here is what I have tried.

- Changed errorMode to Detailed. Still getting the 500 error page instead of the php error.
- Removed all of the custom errors in the default IIS config file under the "httpErrors" block. Still getting the IIS custom 500 error page.
- Added existingResponse="PassThrough" to my httpErrors block in the default IIS config. Doing this causes me to get a blank page instead of the php error, or the IIS 500 error.
- I have verified that none of these settings are being overwritten in the site default system.config files.

Currently I am getting a blank page instead of the IIS 500 error on the screen. I have already verified that display_errors is on, and error_reporting is correct. I also know that the php page runs just fine. I am purposely causing this php error by removing a semi-colon on the page. So I already know everything is working fine. PHP Error logging is also working, but I want the errors to display on the page so I dont have to look at the error log every 5 minutes.

What else could be causing this?

Comment: Why are you uisng IIS 6.2?

Comment: @dai From what I have read, the version of IIS is specific to the version of the OS. I am running windows 8.1 right now, and this is what was installed. It looked to me like IIS 7 was for Windows Server. This is for local dev purposes btw.

Comment: look at the server error logs for details about the 500. at least get a clue as to what the cause could be, instead of flailing around trying random things.

Comment: @Metropolis The IIS version number has no relation to the Windows version number. Windows 8.1 has IIS 8.5, not 6.2 (Windows 8.1 is fundamentally the same as Server 2012 R2)

Comment: @MarcB The 500 error is one I am purposely causing in PHP to fix this specific problem. Maybe you should try and not assume.

Comment: @Dai Well if I go into the about section under IIS, it says version 6.2. I will try and install a higher version. That still is not what my problem is.

Comment: @Dai Can I just going into the platform installer and install IIS 7.5 express?

Comment: @Metropolis the "Help > About" version displayed in IIS Manager is the Windows version, not IIS. The current IIS version is at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\VersionString` in your registry. You cannot upgrade IIS on Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

Comment: @Metropolis I don't personally recommend IIS Express when you already have the full version of IIS installed.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the tip on the version number. I am running 8.5. I come from an Apache background, so IIS is still a little bit new to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**IF** you set custom error to `Detailed` in feature settings of `error pages` for website and server both

**AND** if in your `php.ini` file you set the `display_errors = on` & `error_reporting = E_ALL`

**THEN** there is only one possibility for getting [IIS default 500 error page] is that *"Your PHP is not working coz of miss configuration."*

**The required configurations are:**

After setting `Handler Mappings` to your php-cgi.exe file(which is in you php installation dir) as FastCGI, open the `php.ini` file and **edit following lines OR add if not found** in file. (if php.ini is not exists in you PHP installation dir then rename from existing php.ini-development OR php.ini-production)

1) `extension_dir = "ext\"`

;ext folder will be in PHP installation, if not create and don't forget ending \

2) `log_errors = On`

3) `error_log = "C:\inetpub\temp\php-errors.log"`

4) `cgi.force_redirect = 0`

; may be you need to add this line add it anywhere, for instance-before '; File Uploads ;'

5) `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`

6) `fastcgi.impersonate = 1`

7) `fastcgi.logging = 0`

```
 Be careful and there should not `;` before any of these lines.
```

see [documentation - installing/configuring PHP](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)

Even after correct configurations PHP may not work because of system corruption. You can check by double click on `php-cgi.exe` and `php-win.exe` it should run without proper error (other then warnings OR `ext/fileName...` is missing messages - these are OK).

**Note:** after these many other setting are requires to run all things of php (ex. session), but by these SIMPLE PHP WILL WORK or PHP will properly show the error for what's wrong (NOT 500 page).

Comment: Adarsh,
A good way to tell people how to see if php is installed and configured correctly is to add a php file to the web root that consists of:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

and run it. You'll get the php info page if php is set up on the IIS web host correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are editing the right php.ini file.  To check which file needs to be edited, go to IIS > Handler Mappings and look for PHP.  Then check which directory they are located in.

In my case, I had two directories and was editing the wrong php.ini file, which was the reason why I was unable to get the errors to display.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue getting a 500 error instead of a PHP error.  I fixed the issue by going to PHP Manager within IIS

Under PHP Settings click configure error reporting. This will allow you to choose between Development and Production machine.  If you choose Production you will get no detailed PHP errors in the browser, you will only get wrritten to a logfile. Development will allow for both errors to be displayed and written to a logfile.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**If ou are Getting error 500 when active php to show errors, maybe you need to turn off the tracking error**
Follow the step by step to fix.

*If you don't have downnload the PHP Manager for IIS, you can find it in Web Platform Installer. Then open it.*
[image]

*After that click on manage all settings*
[image]

*Now Just turn off this setting*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

under server configuration feature view you see fast-cgi settings,
double click it. you see php-cgi.exe. double click it. set standart error mode to IgnoreAndReturn200.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue - I have my PHP Handler Mapping set as follows, confirming I'm using PHP 5.3:

[image]

Therefore I then went to the corresponding location to find the correct file, here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3` and edited `php.ini`

At first it looked like this:

```
; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I changed it to this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I had to restart the Server in IIS to apply the change (choosing the Server from the list at the top on the left hand side, rather than selecting the Site on the left, lower down):

[image]

Now I see the error message - e.g.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\data\test.php on line 2**

Instead of this type of generic error - e.g. on Chrome:

[image]