# YII2 An internal server error occurred in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis-8, yii2-advanced-app

I used composer to successfully install and run yii2 version 2.0.10 in my laptop using xampp but when I installed it in windows server 2012 r2 with IIS v 8.5, it shows `An internal server error occurred` error. I did not change or edited any of the files from the fresh installation.

[image]
[image]

I tried renaming the `index.php` and created new `index.php` with just simple echo and it worked fine.

EDIT - here is the server log.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-01-05 23:56:51
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-01-05 23:56:51 ::1 GET /advanced/frontend/web/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/advanced/frontend/ 500 0 0 5893
2017-01-05 23:56:56 ::1 GET /advanced/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 21
2017-01-05 23:56:59 ::1 GET /advanced/frontend/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/advanced/ 200 0 0 3
2017-01-05 23:57:01 ::1 GET /advanced/frontend/web/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/advanced/frontend/ 500 0 0 103
2017-01-05 23:59:35 ::1 GET /advanced/frontend/web/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/advanced/frontend/ 500 0 0 61
2017-01-05 23:59:35 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/ 404 0 2 10
```

EDIT 2.

Tried installing new one under `development` and it now gave different error.

[image]

Comment: Check `frontend/runtime/logs/app.log` for errors.

Comment: logs folder is empty.

Comment: So you need to check server errors log.

Comment: This is access log, you need error PHP error log.

Comment: thanks for trying to help but where do I find that php error log? I have a newly installed windows server 2012.

Comment: I'm not using IIS but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27777574/3364821) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Yii is .htaccess for its mod-rewrite configuration. Do you convert it to an equivalent web.config so IIS can interpret it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **web.config** file in **frontend/web/** and in the **backend/web/**

**IIS Does Not Support .htaccess Files**

***Content of web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule> 
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image: backend web screenshot]

[image: frontend web screenshot]