# Youtube data API V3 PHP on IIS web server not working

Tags: php, api, iis, youtube, google-api-php-client

I am trying out the YouTube data API V3 using PHP on a IIS web server (version 8.5.9600). I followed the instructions provided, installed the PHP code samples, API client library using composer, and setup the developer API key etc... https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

When trying out the search function on the PHP code samples, it returns a blank page.

I did the same but with a XAMPP installation with Apache web server (version 2.4.25) and it works fine. The problem is when I use the IIS web server. The code is exactly the same since I just copied the files, the PHP version is also the same PHP 7, I also tried with PHP 7.1. The web servers are installed on a Windows 8.1 machine.

I would really love to know how I can make the YouTube API work under PHP in IIS.

Comment: Do the IIS error logs tell you anything useful?

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608688/display-php-errors-in-iis

Comment: Unfortunatly the IIS logs do not tell me anything usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue thanks to Hackerman. I followed the related question to enable the error messages on the webserver. The error was a cURL error 60. I managed to fix it by following another thread - [PHP cURL error code 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60).

Now everything is ok!